# Is it possible to integrate a custom login feature with wordpress?

Tags: customization, login, authentication

I'm looking for a way for members of my site to be able to post comments on the site's wordpress blog, and have their name and avatar from the site show up next to their comments.

Is there a way to link wordpress to the site's custom login system to let the members of my site login and be able to post from their names and avatars?

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of plugins to do this. It sounds like you're looking for JetPack's rather new comment module. There are also powerful commenting plugins like Disqus and LiveFyre.